# Visual Studio Community: Designer won't load/Unhandled exception

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Since I upgraded to Windows 10/VSC, creating Universal App projects just won't work, designer won't load and displays this:

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.MetadataStore.GetTypeConverter(Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsUIXamlDesignTimeProperties.ResolveImplementation(IPlatformMetadata platformMetadata, DesignTimePropertyId neutralProperty, IType declaringType, PropertyChangedCallback callback)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsUIXamlDesignTimeProperties.RegisterProperty(IPropertyId neutralPropertyKey, IType declaringType, PropertyChangedCallback callback)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsUIXamlCommonDesignTimeProperties.Initialize(WindowsUIXamlDesignTimeProperties designTimeProperties)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsUIXamlDesignTimeProperties..ctor(IPlatformTypes platformMetadata)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UniversalXamlDesigner.UniversalXamlPlatformMetadata.CreateDesignTimeProperties()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Metadata.WindowsUIXamlPlatformMetadata.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsStoreXamlPlatform.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.PlatformCreatorBase.CreatePlatform(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver referenceAssemblyResolver)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.
    <>c__DisplayClass12_0.
        <Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.
            <>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.
                <MarshalInWithCancellation>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.
                    <>c__DisplayClass14_0.
                        <Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.
                            <>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.
                                <MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService ds)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.
                                    <>c__DisplayClass27_0`1.
                                        <MarshalOut>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
```

There are very few threads currently that deal with this issue; needless to say, I've tried the following recommendations and they do not work:

1. Deleting environment variables in advanced system settings (um, where are the environment variables?)
2. Deleting the files in the following folder(s):
   C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Designer\ShadowCache

The issue only occurs when I attempt to code any kind of Universal App and some of my existing WPF projects I noticed wouldn't load the designer either.

Hardware:
AMD A10-6700 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 3.70 GHz
12.0 GB installed memory
64-bit Windows 10

Software:
Visual Studio Community 2015 64-bit

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I too am having the same issue. I recently updated my VS 2015 Community Edition to Update 1, and had noticed all my UWP projects would no longer run. The designer also gave me the same errors you did, and trying to run any application I also am met with some problems before the application even runs, or Win32 projects too.

I will say I managed to resolve my problems by just doing a reset on my Windows 10 system. It only helped partially because my projects are mostly on my D:\ and those still will not run. If I run a project or create one on my C:\ where my OS was refreshed, they can run fine.

I am suspecting it may be something else, every project I open again on my D:\ is asking for "elevated permissions" and even when I allow it to do so, it doesn't resolve my problem. If you're experiencing this issue as well, I haven't found any way to deal with it, but if your setup is all contained on one drive, dry doing a clean install of VS again, see if it helps, otherwise maybe you can just do a reset on your OS too, if it isn't going to be too much trouble.

Comment: Ultimately, I ended up reinstalling my version of Windows 10 and haven't had any problems since. Probably just a bug, if anything, but seems fixed now :)